# I'm getting an error while running this code snippit. I seems like the code is unable to create the numpy array.I think it's running an infinite loop

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

# Set mediapipe model 
with mp_holistic.Holistic(min_detection_confidence=0.5, min_tracking_confidence=0.5) as holistic:
    
    # NEW LOOP
    # Loop through actions
    for action in actions:
        # Loop through sequences aka videos
        for sequence in range(start_folder, start_folder+no_sequences):
            # Loop through video length aka sequence length
            for frame_num in range(sequence_length):

                # Read feed
                ret, frame = cap.read()
                cv2.startWindowThread()

                # Make detections
                image, results = mediapipe_detection(frame, holistic)

                # Draw landmarks
                draw_styled_landmarks(image, results)
                
                # NEW Apply wait logic
                if frame_num == 0: 
                    cv2.putText(image, 'STARTING COLLECTION', (120,200), 
                               cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 1, (0,255, 0), 4, cv2.LINE_AA)
                    cv2.putText(image, 'Collecting frames for {} Video Number {}'.format(action, sequence), (15,12), 
                               cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.5, (0, 0, 255), 1, cv2.LINE_AA)
                    # Show to screen
                    cv2.imshow('OpenCV data collection Feed', image)
                    cv2.waitKey(1)

                else: 
                    cv2.putText(image, 'Collecting frames for {} Video Number {}'.format(action, sequence), (15,12), 
                               cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.5, (0, 0, 255), 1, cv2.LINE_AA)
                    # Show to screen
                    cv2.imshow('OpenCV data collection Feed', image)
                
                # NEW Export keypoints
                keypoints = extract_keypoints(results)
                npy_path = os.path.join(DATA_PATH, action, str(sequence), str(frame_num))
                np.save(npy_path, keypoints)

                # break
                if cv2.waitKey(10) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
                    break
                    
    cap.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
    cv2.waitKey(1)
```

code cell for data collection using OpenCV and the MediaPipe library. It sets up a video capture from the default camera (index 0) using cv2.VideoCapture(0) and initializes a MediaPipe holistic model.

The code then enters a loop that iterates over a list of actions. Within each action, it loops over a range of sequences and within each sequence, it loops over the frames. For each frame, it reads the video feed using cap.read() and performs detections using mediapipe_detection() function. It then draws landmarks on the frame using draw_styled_landmarks().

the error I am getting is

```
FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[58], line 43
     41 keypoints = extract_keypoints(results)
     42 npy_path = os.path.join(DATA_PATH, action, str(sequence), str(frame_num))
---> 43 np.save(npy_path, keypoints)
     45 # break
     46 if cv2.waitKey(10) & 0xFF == ord('q'):

File <__array_function__ internals>:180, in save(*args, **kwargs)

File ~/miniconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.10/site-packages/numpy/lib/npyio.py:518, in save(file, arr, allow_pickle, fix_imports)
    516     if not file.endswith('.npy'):
    517         file = file + '.npy'
--> 518     file_ctx = open(file, "wb")
    520 with file_ctx as fid:
    521     arr = np.asanyarray(arr)

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/Users/utkx2/Desktop/python/MLDL/Projects/Human-Action-Recognition/MP_Data/hello/31/0.npy'
```

my folders for storing the data have been created but I don't know why it's unable to create the numpy files for storing the numpy array values. Kindly Help. I'm using an M1 Mac (just for reference in case it's an OS issue or something)

Comment: The error is very clear: `No such file or directory: '/Users/utkx2/Desktop/python/MLDL/Projects/Human-Action-Recognition/MP_Data/hello/31/0.npy`  you are trying to open a file that doesn;t exist

Comment: The error isn't about creating an array.  It's about finding the directory to `save` it to. `FileNotFoundError`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to create the full path where you are saving your numpy array, more specific, you need to make all the subfolders in the defined path:

```
npy_path = os.path.join(DATA_PATH, action, str(sequence), str(frame_num))
np.save(npy_path, keypoints)
```

So you can call os.makedirs(npy_path, exit_ok=True) before calling np.save, the parameter exit_ok=true will not create the folders if they were already created.

```
npy_path = os.path.join(DATA_PATH, action, str(sequence), str(frame_num))
os.makedirs(npy_path, exit_ok=True)
np.save(npy_path, keypoints)
```